# set weight units in grams

Tags: product, shipping, fedex

i am using magento to sell jewelry products , i want my weight to be set in grams , not in kg or grams , i tried searching and found only two kg and pounds.

weights are important is used by fedex for calculation .

please guide me where can i find setting to edit it .

Comment: When i changed to lbs its not calculating, leave it as default, and convert products weight grams to lbs (ex : 50 gram = 0.110231  lbs)  then only calculating freight cost,  we don't need to change 'Units' = 'LBS'.      How its working for you.... Does you changed or not 'Units' = 'LBS'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your store offers multiple shipping methods to your customers, it’s important to align all shippers to use the same unit for weight.

This is becuase weight in Magento is not actually a particular unit. Weight to Magento is just a number, so theoretically, could be grams, kilograms, pounds, tonnes, you name it.

Realistically, you want to choose either pounds (lbs)or Kilograms (Kgs) as these are the main two used by shipping providers who deal with weight-based shipping estimates. The only thing that’s important is to keep whichever unit you choose uniform throughout the whole of your store. So if you use Lbs with UPS, you want to keep Lbs with FedEx etc.

Using Kg (as some stores do) poses a little snag, as FedEx shipping method in Magento only uses Lbs when calculating shipping estimate costs. However there is a quick fix to this:

```
Copy  /app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/FedEx.php 

and paste it under

Copy  /app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/FedEx.php
```

…and update the value for LBS, changing it here for ‘KG':

```
'RequestedPackageLineItems' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'Weight' => array(
                    'Value' => (float)$r->getWeight(),
                    'Units' => 'LBS'
                ),
                'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
            )
```

Comment: @ Praful Rajput :    When i changed to lbs its not calculating, leave it as default, and convert products weight grams to lbs (ex : 50 gram = 0.110231  lbs)  then only calculating freight cost,  we don't need to change 'Units' = 'LBS'.