# Magento 2 i would like to add a weight unit in grams

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute

As I am new in Magento 2 development I am trying to add a weight unit Grams in weight drop down on product addition page on admin console but I can't get success. Can anyone please help me on this to add a new weight unit Grams?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need to override `\magento\vendor\magento\module-directory\Model\Config\Source\WeightUnit.php`

**magento\app\code\Custom\Directory\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Directory',
    __DIR__
);
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Directory\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Directory" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Directory\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\WeightUnit" type="Custom\Directory\Model\Config\Source\WeightUnit" />
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Directory\Model\Config\Source\WeightUnit.php**

```
namespace Custom\Directory\Model\Config\Source;

class WeightUnit extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\WeightUnit
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [['value' => 'lbs', 'label' => __('lbs')], ['value' => 'kgs', 'label' => __('kgs')], ['value' => 'gms', 'label' => __('grams')]];
    }
}
```

**Note: Be careful with your shipping methods. DHL, UPS, FedEx they allow only KG & LBS.**

Reference for Magento 1 [set weight units in grams](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76816/set-weight-units-in-grams)

Comment: Thanks! I have made a module using your code, hope it helps others
https://github.com/harshvardhanmalpani/Magento2-Extend-Weight-Units

Comment: How I can add multiple units in a dropdown with a text field in the product update details in the admin end?