# How to use Different units for Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, shipping, ce-1.9.2.2

We recently start a store which includes grocery, clothing, and jewelry on this when I upload product for grocery and other we facing a problem. All product weight are considering Kgs or Lbs but we are using Oz, Kgs, Lbs, packets and grams for grocery.

My question is: **How to change weight units for a different product, How to assign particular weight unit for products?**

Is there any extension or have any customization need to do for Backend. 
and one more question is If I change weight units How to consider Units for shipping?

Comment: Just a note that Magento 2 redefines the weight field as explicitly denominated in either lbs or kg. Thus if you are considering moving to Magento 2 at some point, you would be best to keep your actual weight values in the database all consistently in one of those units. If you want to handle different units in the catalog, have it be a frontend feature that converts dynamically from the database value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there would be some extention for your need but i just let you know my opinion without extension. First of all, you need to add attribute. Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes.

And you can add new attribute you would use for weight unit and you can edit some options on Attribute Information > Manage Label/Option. You can add Oz, Kgs, Lbs, packets and grams for grocery.

And then, go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets and make 'Grocery' attribute. Then, you can add attribute you need.

Or,you can change the property of weight attribute like text input. There is a way to write unit directly for each product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have one question **If I change weight units How to consider Units for shipping**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an extension called `Product Units and Quantities`

https://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_units_and_quantities.html

With it you can make predefined qty selections as drop-down menu so you can allow customers to order for example 25kg or 50kg of certain product and the amount is then deducted from the stock qty of the product.

Comment: My store in India, so my default weight KGS. UPS for USA shipping, what i need to do with "Weight Unit"   KGS or LBS?

Comment: @zus this might help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76816/set-weight-units-in-grams